# Experience Table Algorithm Curve

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

Say I want to make a unique curve, either a **Bezier curve** or **Exponential Curve**, but I want these curves to be defined by a specific set of parameters.

Lets take for example the following below.

**Levels**: [1, 2, 3, ..., 100]

**Experience Accumulative**: [100, 500, 10000, ..., 30000000]

Now if I specify level 100 as being 30,000,000 million, how do I make it so that whatever curve algorithm I throw at it, it will follow suit and curve the other levels so that the total sum of all their experiences will equal to 30,000,000 million.

I.e. Level 1-100 = 30,000,000 million experience total required. The experience needed per each level is based on a math curve provided being either a custom curve/Bezier curve/exponential curve.

In the example above, if there was no first levels provided, what type of algorithm would I use to determine the remaining levels experience needed per each one based on a curve?

30,000,000 (accumulative xp from level 1 to 100) = level 100

25,000,000 (accumulative xp from level 1 to 100) = level 99

From top to Bottom: Learning Curve, Exponential Curve, Custom Curve.

Curve Example Images Below

[Curve Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjFFh.jpg)

Comment: Sketch the curve that you want.

Comment: Added them, let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You want to get 30000000 as a sum of inputs 1..100, just multiply the result of a function by constant.

```
double[] GetExperienceLimits(int experienceLevels, int maximumExperienceSum, Func<int, double> func)
{            
    var arr = Enumerable.Range(1, experienceLevels)
        .Select(i => func(i))
        .ToArray();
    double c = maximumExperienceSum / arr.Sum();
    return arr.Select(f => f * c).ToArray();
}
```

You use it like this

```
var arr = GetExperienceLimits(4, 300, i => i * i);
```

and get

10, 40, 90, 160

Comment: Thank you for your comment, this indeed will get me the specific amount on levels of the last one being 3,000,000. But what I need is the ability to have the Accumulative XP = 3,000,000 from level 1 to 100. I reworded my question to address that issue. Thank you again for your response, definitely gives me something else to play with for trying to figure this out.

Comment: Thank you, I can use this plus the previous persons answer together to get what I need!

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the sketches, I guess that 1D natural cubic splines are the most appropriate, because

- they define a function (not a curve),
- they are interpolating, i.e. go through the points that you specify.

The learning and exponential curves will probably take 3 points, and the custom one 4 points.

This link shows how it works: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/560163/Csharp-Cubic-Spline-Interpolation

Comment: I think the combining answer of both you and the guy who answered before is the correct way to go. Simply having the function where it would give me the correct experience payload and then manipulate it from there from the correct graph seems to be working best. Thank you so much for answering with this, really helpful.